# Reactjs Yup dropdownlist Form Validation

Tags: reactjs, yup

I am doing a form validation in reactjs using YUP. I wrote the  form validation as follows -

```
const FromValidation = Yup.object().shape({
    nameId: Yup.object()
    .nullable()
    .required('name is requried'),
    classId: Yup.object()
    .nullable()
    .required('class is required'),
    statusId: Yup.object()
    .nullable()
    .when('classId',{
        is:(val) => val === 1,
        then: Yup.object()
            .nullable()
            .required('status is required')
    }
})
```

The null validations are working fine. But validation for statusid is not working. I want to display 'status is required' only if classId is 1.
Kindly point me out where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your schema states that `classId` is an object. How can an object equal `1`?

Comment: @JakeWorth Hello Jake thanks for the comment. Can you please suggest me how can I do the validation. I am novice in Reatjs. Thanks.

Comment: @JakeWorth  class is a dropdownlist. The classId = 1 corresponds to 'TinyTots'. If I put val === 'TinyTots', its still not working. Could you please point out how can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `classId` select when you want to require status? Focusing the select in Chrome DevTools and then executing `$0.value` in the console would tell you. That value is the condition you need to match in your `is`.